# an android activity with listView works but not in debug mode

Tags: android, android-layout, debugging, listview, usb

I know it could seem quite strange, but I have an Activity not working in usb debug mode and instead it works when I disconnect usb cable. Has someone idea of the reason why?
I post the Activity below:

```
 package com.wikibuyers.aforismi;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

 public class PreferitiActivity extends Activity{

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE =      "com.example.provacomunicazione.MESSAGE";
private static final int DIALOG_ALERT_ID = 1;
SharedPreferences savedPreferiti;
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
ListView listView = null;

@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.preferiti);

      savedPreferiti=getSharedPreferences("preferiti", MODE_PRIVATE);
      String[] listaFrasi = savedPreferiti.getAll().keySet().toArray(new    String[0]);




       Button reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);



      reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {reset();}
      });



      ArrayList<String> Frasi = new ArrayList<String>();

      for (int i=0;i<listaFrasi.length;++i){


          Frasi.add(savedPreferiti.getString("Frase"+i, "Frase"+i));
      }







      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  (getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_2, Frasi);

     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);

      listView.setAdapter(adapter);

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) { String frase = (String) (((TextView)view).getText())  ;

                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, frase);
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");


                    showDialog(DIALOG_ALERT_ID);
            }
        });




   }



@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch (id) {

    case DIALOG_ALERT_ID:
        dialog = createAlertDialog();
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}




private Dialog createAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Attenzione");
    builder.setMessage("Solo per Facebook bisogna incollare il testo sulla  casella di condivisione tenendo premuto a lungo e cliccando sul popup ''incolla'' che  compare");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Condividi  la frase con:"));
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_ALERT_ID);

        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    return alert;

  }



  public void reset(){



         String[] listaFrasi = savedPreferiti.getAll().keySet().toArray(new String[0]);


                if (listaFrasi.length>=1){

                    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedPreferiti.edit();
                preferencesEditor.remove("Frase"+(listaFrasi.length-1));   //cancella l'ultimo preferito della lista

                 preferencesEditor.commit();

                 Intent intent = getIntent();
                 finish();
                 startActivity(intent); 
                }
}
```

}

This is layout preferiti.xml charged by the Activity:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/src/com.wikibuyers.aforismi"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/preferiti"
    android:textColor="#DDF3FF"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="36sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp" >


</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Elimina l'ultima frase"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/angolismussatibackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally list item called list_item_2.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/src/com.wikibuyers.aforismi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#DDF3FF"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    style="@style/menuTextViewStyle.Corsivo"
    android:background="@drawable/angolismussatibackgroundgradiente" 
    android:padding="20dp"
/>
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to explain, "not working".

Comment: Post your logcat where your error is.

Comment: when it's not working in debug, maybe you have a breakpoint set?

Comment: Yes I'll post it as soon as possible but I had a new error and I can't. Thanks for patience

Comment: Know appears an exclamation mark befor project name and I can't run my app at all! But there are no further inner error marks

Comment: @Domenico Pacecca Go to your project properties, by clicking right button on it and then Java Build path. Check if all the libraries are ok and no jar is missing.

Comment: @joao.. thanks very much I fixed the problem with your indications. If you post an answer I'll vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by joao2fast4u it was a problem of libraries I have repristened.